# Calculate and collect years between dates

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I have a dataset with election date for each country.
I want to create a variable listing all years in which the winner ruled based on the years that pass between elections.
I know that some election data might be missing (e.g. 2004 in the toy example) and that the maximum amount of years an administration can rule is 5.

```
toy <- data.frame(
  election_year=c(1995,1999,2009,2014),
  election_country=rep("A",4))
```

This is what I expect the result to look like:

```
toy_expected <- data.frame(
  election_year=c(1995,1999,2009,2014),
  election_country =rep("A",4),
  ruling_year=c("1995 - 1996 - 1997 - 1998",
                "1999 - 2000 - 2001 - 2002 - 2003",
                "2009 - 2010 - 2011 - 2012 - 2013",
                "2014 - 2015 - 2016 - 2017 - 2018"))

> toy_expected
  election_year election_city                      ruling_year
1          1995             A        1995 - 1996 - 1997 - 1998
2          1999             A 1999 - 2000 - 2001 - 2002 - 2003
3          2009             A 2009 - 2010 - 2011 - 2012 - 2013
4          2014             A 2014 - 2015 - 2016 - 2017 - 2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the steps I would take:

1. Create a helper function that generates a ruling year string based on start and end
2. Calculate the end year for each row - initially set this as the following election year, then check to make sure this is a valid number (not NA or result in more than 5 years)
3. Map over your start and end years to generate the column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

genYearString <- function(start, end){
  paste(seq(start, end), collapse = " - ")
}

toy %>% 
  mutate(
    end_year = dplyr::lead(election_year) - 1,
    end_year = if_else(
      is.na(end_year) | (end_year - election_year) > 4,
      election_year + 4, 
      end_year
    ),
    ruling_year = map2_chr(election_year, end_year, genYearString)
  ) %>% 
  select(-end_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ruling_years <- function(x,y){
  r = c(x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4)
  r = setdiff(r,y)
  r = c(x,r)
  r = paste(r, collapse = " - ")
  return(r)
}


toy %>% 
  group_by(election_city) %>% 
  mutate(e_years=list(election_year),
         r=mapply(ruling_years,election_year,e_years)) %>% 
  select(-e_years)
```